# How to print the maximum of multiple functions in Gnuplot

Tags: max, gnuplot

My question is pretty basic. I am plotting several functions at once using gnuplot, and I want to print out (in either a file or on the graph itself) the maximum y-values of every function. Any idea how I could do that?

I looked into STATS and GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX but I can't really figure out how to make them work with several functions at the same time.

Without going into too much details, let's suppose that my file looks like that :

```
plot 'file1.dat' us 1:2 title "file1" w lines,\
     'file2.dat' us 1:2 title "file2" w lines,\
     'file3.dat' us 1:2 title "file3" w lines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `name` parameter of the `stats` option to save the maximum of every file in a different set of variables:

```
stats 'file1.dat' using 2 nooutput name 'file1'
stats 'file2.dat' using 2 nooutput name 'file2'
stats 'file3.dat' using 2 nooutput name 'file3'
```

Now you can either print the values to an external file

```
set print 'max.dat'
print file1_max
print file2_max
print file3_max
```

If you want to place a respective label near the maximum in your graph, you must also know the corresponding x-value where the data has its maximum. This data is not readily available from the first `stats` command, only its index in the data file. So you need an additional call to `stats` in order to get the x-value where the maximum y-value was:

```
stats 'file1.dat' using 1 every ::file1_index_max::file1_index_max name 'file1_x'
...
```

And then you can use

```
set label center at first file1_x_max,first file1_max sprintf('y = %.2f', file1_max) offset char 0,1
```

Unfortunately, most of the commands cannot be iterated properly with changing variable names.